# What goes wrong shooting a club on $\kappa >\aleph_1$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading through Jech's book, and in the section **Stationary Sets in Generic Extensions** (pages 444 and 445), he remarks that the poset used in shooting a club through a stationary $S\subseteq\omega_1$ can be generalized for regular $\kappa>\aleph_1$, but with additional restrictions on the stationary subset we use in order to preserve $\kappa$.

Why do we need these restrictions?  What goes wrong in the usual argument if we consider, say, $\aleph_2$?

Is it that all club subsets of ordinals $\alpha<\omega_1$ have countable cofinality, while those $\alpha<\omega_2$ might have confinality $\omega_1$ or $\omega$?

Comment: Abraham, Uri; Shelah, Saharon_, [**Forcing closed unbounded sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2273456), J. Symb. Log. 48, 643-657 (1983). [ZBL0568.03024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0568.03024).